# Pyramid ignore custom exception

Tags: python, pyramid

i think i might have a problem using pyramid and dealing with custom error code / exception

In the back end application, im raising a `errareCatalog.errExtapiFulfillIdDeprecated` when a specific events occurs, i dont think it's significant but here's what i'm raising in my `errareCatalog.py` :

```
class errExtapiFulfillIdDeprecated(errare.processingErrare):
  e_mnemonic = 'ERR_FULFILL_ID_DEPRECATED'
  e_baseMsg = gettext('Fulfill id is deprecated')
  e_errCatalogNumber = -21008
```

I'm trying to catch this exception in the front end part this way :

```
from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPNotFound
from hll.errors import errareCatalog

try :
  stuff that raise and exception
except errareCatalog.errExtapiFulfillIdDeprecated as ex :
  request.response.status_code = 404
  print 'throwin 404'
  return HTTPNotFound()
```

The problem is, i never seem to enter in this except. A 500 error is thrown somewhere and redirect me to the 500 page.
Am i doing something wrong with the way i raise / catch exceptions or do i have a configuration missing in Pyramid ?

Edit : here's my exception view

```
@view_config(context=errareCatalog.errExtapiFulfillIdDeprecated, permission=NO_PERMISSION_REQUIRED)
def mobile_ticket_error(exc, request):
  print 'test error'
  logger.exception("DEPRECATED FULFILLID: %s" % str(exc))   
  return render_to_response("mylogin:templates/mobile-ticket-error.genshi",
                            {'message': str(exc),
                            'layout_name': get_layout_name(request)},
                            request=request)
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the `try` block and check what exception is actually getting thrown?

Comment: @brianpck How can i do a `try: except` block without the try ?

Comment: Just remove both and then don't catch the exception (I'm assuming this isn't a production issue)

Comment: i'm still getting redirected to my custom 500 error page, i've edited my question to include the view i'm using when im in a `errExtapiFulfillIdDeprecated` context

Comment: You likely have an unrelated error somewhere in your code - like a missing import etc., and that causes your custom exception to never be raised. Check your app's console output or logs.

Comment: Also, the "I'm trying to catch this exception in the front end part this way" part is strange and not needed - is this code at module level? (very strange) or in a view function? (not needed if you want to use a custom exception view). Just remove the try/except block there if you want to use an exception view.  To add to my first comment: another possibility is that the error happens in your `mobile_ticket_error` handler so it re-throws an unrelated exception.

Comment: I have an unrelated comment which is that `HTTPNotFound()` is a separate response object from `request.response` so your line above (`request.response.status_code = 404`) is basically a no-op here because you are returning your own response object explicitly instead.

Comment: It looks like an exception is being raised elsewhere. You could turn on the `pyramid_debugtoolbar` which can output more logging information about unhandled exceptions during development.